# Sum occurrences of string for each row of a matrix using awk

Tags: awk, array, r

I have a very long data frame (~11 million x 130) for which is sparsely filled with percentages (0.00 - 100.00, float).

The entries that are missing are labeled "NA", like so:

```
cat1    NA    NA    99.90    NA    NA    10.90    NA
cat2    NA    1.00    NA    19.12    NA    NA    NA  
cat3    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    45.00
```

I want to go through this data frame row by row and sum up the occurrences of "NA".

I can normally accomplish this very easily in R by doing `apply(data.frame, 1, function(x) sum(is.na(x))`, but because the file is so large I keep having memory problems. I'd like to do this with AWK if possible so that I can apply this on the command line for future similar problems.

I am not great with awk, but I essentially want to sum the occurrences of "NA" across fields for each record/row and then later I can use this as an index for skipping lines of the file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: to sum up `NA` across all rows **at once**, or get sum for each separate record?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest sum for each separate record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straightforwardly:

```
$ awk '{ for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="NA") c++; print c; c=0 }' file
5
5
6
```

Comment: Yeah this looks like it works. I'm not super familiar w/ the internal workings of AWK, but is this mechanism efficient for ~10 million records? would a gsub() based method work more efficiently?

Comment: @Reilstein, the better way is to try both approaches on your actual data

Comment: in the process of doing that now, thanks!

Comment: both methods worked sufficiently fast for this use case. I will remember this for future large datasets. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a string replacement function that matches the pattern `NA` and count the number of occurrences it is doing per line and sum it up for the whole file as below.

```
awk '{ sum += gsub(/NA/, "", $0) } END { print sum }' file
```

or make it more robust to avoid false matches to the pattern `NA`. The below regex is based on your input sample where `NA` does not appear at the start of the file.

```
awk '{ sum += gsub(/[[:space:]]*NA[[:space:]]*|[[:space:]]*NA$/, "", $0) } END { print sum }' file
```

Comment: Yes i think this could work. I want the sum for each individual record, so would I just change it to `awk '{ sum += gsub(/NA/, "", $0)} {print sum}' file ` ?

Comment: @Reilstein : Yes that could work!

Comment: actually it would be `awk '{ sum += gsub(/NA/, "", $0)} {print sum; sum=0}' file`

Answer (score 0):

- table without header:`awk '{ sum += gsub(/[[:space:]]*NA[[:space:]]*|[[:space:]]*NA$/, "", $0) ; print sum }' file`
- table with header:`awk 'NR > 1{ sum += gsub(/[[:space:]]*NA[[:space:]]*|[[:space:]]*NA$/, "", $0) ; print sum }' file`

Comment: How is this answer different from the one of Inian ?